# Catch import warnings in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file `A.py` with only the following contents:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("A is deprecated", DeprecationWarning)
```

I want to catch this warning when I import A and assert that it is a `DeprecationWarning`. Currently I'm doing the following:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    import A
```

and trying to assert using something like `assert_equal(w[0].category, DeprecationWarning)` but it shows that `w` is empty. It isn't catching the warning I guess. Is there any other way to do this?

*EDIT*: I forgot to add that I tried it with `warnings.simplefilter("always")`, but no warning was recorded.

*EDIT 2*: It could have something to do with warning levels. [see comments]

*EDIT 3*: Tried it with different `stacklevel`s - 0, 1, 2, 3. No effect :|

Comment: If you're using [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), there's a [`unittest.TestCase.assertWarns()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertWarns).

Comment: What is your warning level? I believe `DeprecationWarning` is [ignored by default](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filters). Try calling `warnings.simplefilter('default')`  before `catch_warnings` (or call `python -Wd` to run your script) as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html#updating-code-for-new-versions-of-python). See the full example [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I tried it with `warnings.simplefilter('always')`, but no warning was recorded, will `EDIT` the question.

Comment: @CarlGroner, I added `default` in place of `always` and the warning is being recorded now. Will check it for Python 2.7 and 2.6 too.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point me to something which explains warning levels, as I'm new to this. :)

Comment: So when I run all the tests, it shows that `w` is empty (no warning is recorded) but when I do this via the Python interpreter by hand, warning is recorded. Must have something to do with warning levels.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the line

```
warnings.simplefilter("always")
```

to your code, like this:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    import A
```

So, a working version of 'B.py' (as it were) might look like this:

```
import warnings
import unittest

class TestWarnings(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_warnings(self):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
            warnings.simplefilter("always")
            import A
            self.assertEqual(w[0].category, DeprecationWarning)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```